# Penguin diagram for $K\rightarrow 2\pi$ process

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, effective-field-theory, mesons

Studying the $\Delta S=1$ effective theory, is well known that QCD corrections and renormalization, give rise to a set of possible effective operators, some of which are known as penguin operators.

Is the following penguin diagram a sensible diagram for the $K\rightarrow 2\pi$ transition?
[image]

Since the dynamics in the quark loop is non-perturbative, I imagine that more than one gluon could be exchanged between the penguin loop and the final quark loop, but for simplicity I've shown only one.

Comment: It is a loop diagram competing with the tree diagrams; did you estimate their relative magnitudes?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I did not. I would imagine a suppression due to the loop factor and the higher order perturbative terms. But beyond this, I am more interested in knowing if this diagram could be a sensible contribution to the QCD-penguin operator matrix element. The doubt comes from the fact that in the usual penguin operator a sum on all possible quarks in the lower fermion line appears while here only the $d$ quark is present.

Comment: It is sensible, alright; nothing disqualifies it.  But why bother involving the heavier quarks? They dominate the loop, but CKM-couple more weakly.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ok, this makes more sense. Thank you!